# PowerMockito fails to mock final method intermittently

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, testng, powermock

I am using TestNG 6.8.8, Mockito 1.9.5 and PowerMock 1.5.4.  When I mock Child class and call stubbed final method, the test passes sometimes and fails sometimes with error MissingMethodInvocationException.

Is this a PowerMock bug?

```
public abstract class Parent implements Serializable {
  protected abstract void validate();

  public final Date getLastModified() {
    return lastModified;
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  @Override
  protected void validate() {
    // nothing for now.
  }
}


import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;
@PrepareForTest({ Parent.class, Child.class })
public class ChildTest {
  @Test
  public final void testChildMethod() {
    Child childObj = PowerMockito.mock(Child.class);
    when(childObj.getLastModified()).thenReturn(new Date());

    TestCodeThatResultsInCallToChild.getLastModified();
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
when() requires an argument which has to be &apos;a method call on a mock&apos;.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don&apos;t call method on mock but on some other object.
3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.
   It is a limitation of the mock engine.
" type="org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException
```

Comment: I'm missing the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` in your code.

Comment: I am using TestNG.  PowerMockRunner.class is only for JUnit, correct?